# Importing gradle project to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have problem with importing [this](https://github.com/dschuermann/android-donations-lib) library into eclipse. Things I did:

- run gradlew.bat (inside project) that downloaded and installed it
- run CMD
- set my SDK with command "set ANDROID_HOME=C:\dev\android-sdk-windows"
- run command gradlew build
- after successful build [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/oi2qx23p4scrcrm/Zrzut%20ekranu%202013-12-27%2019.10.42.png) I tried to import project into my eclipse but it's incomplete (without any classes)

It's first time I'm using gradlew, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19):

This library is built with Android Studio or Intellj.
These steps with Gradle are referred to Android Studio or IntellJ.

I don't know this lib, but if you are using Eclipse, you should do:

- **clone** a copy of this repository, or download it (outside eclipse workspace)
- **import the code in your workspace** starting from library/Donation-lib folder
- **mark java(*)** folder as **source** (click on folder -> Build-Path -> use as source folder). You can also remove the src folder, from the project.
- **mark aidl(*)** folder as **source**
- **add support library** v4 rel.XX ( click -> Android Tools -> Add support library , or just copy android-support-v4.jar in libs folder)
- **mark** your project as **Android Library** (Properties -> Android -> Is library)

(*) **Eclipse** uses `src` and `res` as source folders.
**Android Studio** instead uses `src/main/java` , `src/main/res` and `src/main/aidl` as source **folders**.

Comment: Your answer concluded my research. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open file `build.gradle` and add this line on top:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

In project directory invoke command

```
 gradlew.bat eclipse
```

Open project in Eclipse (import) like normal eclipse project

More info: [Eclipse Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)

Alternatively use dedicated Eclipse plugin [Gradle Integration for Eclipse 3.4.0.RELEASE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse)

Comment: Neither of above support yet Android Gradle

Answer (score 0):

There is a simplest and quick way to import a Gradle project into Eclipse. Just download the **Gradle plugin** for Eclipse from here.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0

And then from import select Gradle and your project would be imported. Then you have to click on **Build Model** to run it.

**EDIT**
Above link for **Gradle plugin** is no more valid. You can use the following link.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration