# AndroidStaggeredGrid Gradle library for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In my RSS reader project I need nice Grid for different sized items(that contain image and text).

I searched for solutions to make a Staggered Grid in Android and came across with [AndroidStaggeredGrid library](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) by Etsy.
I am using Eclipse but library was done for Gradle.

I want to use this library in my Android project. 
I already tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse) but couldn't succeed.
How can I import this library to my Android project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Create an Android Application Project, use any name for the package
  name.
- Flag "Mark this project as library".
- Unflag "Create custom launcher icon" and "Create activity"
- Import the *java* folder of the Etsy library and then "Build Path" > "Use as Source Folder"
- Import
  the *res* folder of the Etsy library overwriting your old res folder.
- Use this in the AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.etsy.android.grid" >
  </manifest>
  ```
- Import Support Library: "Android Tools" > "Add Support Library"
- Remove any other packages in *gen* but "com.etsy.android.grid"
- On your project "Android Tools" > "Fix Project Properties".

It has to work now, you can use the library in your project.