# Use Etsy's StaggeredGridView in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, etsy, staggered-gridview

I wanted to use Etsy's StaggeredGridView in a project of mine on Eclipse. Their gitHub page doesn't provide instructions to import/setup their project in Eclipse. If anyone has successfully done this and can share the steps, it would help a lot!

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

I tried following the steps listed in the link below, but it didn't work.
[Importing gradle project to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse)

Comment: file >> import >> import android project,
 then move the java package from java/main into the src folder

Answer (score 5):

An easy way is to download the ZIP file, extract the entire file to a temp directory, navigate to the `\AndroidStaggeredGrid-master\library\src\main\java` directory, and copy the `com` folder into your project's `src\` directory.  Then go to the `\AndroidStaggeredGrid-master\library\src\main\res\values` directory and copy the `attrs.xml` file to your project's `\res\values\` folder (or merge his file with yours if you already have one).

You don't need Gradle to do this.  The source just becomes part of your project.

Another way is to do this, is to try and create a JAR file from it, but I haven't tried this yet with an Android project.

Comment: have you ever try this method ? How to generate com.etsy.android.grid.R ?

Answer (score 2):

**I have successfully imported the Etsy Staggered GridView into Eclipse. Here are the steps (which work for any Android Studio project you need to get into Eclipse):**

1. Download zip file from Github, unzip, and open project folder --> library --> src --> main
2. Copy all 3 files there: AndroidManifest and the res and src folders
3. Start new project in Eclipse: File --> New --> Android Application Project
4. Create project name, select API levels, etc.. click Next
5. Unclick Create custom icon launcher and Create activity
6. Click Mark this project as library (if to be used as a library)
7. Click Finish
8. Select project title in Package Explorer, then paste those 3 files into there (click "yes to all" to override)
9. (optional) If importing as a library, right click your main project's name, go to Properties --> Android
10. At bottom of popup find "Add" button, select your newly imported library, click ok
11. Done!

Answer (score 0):

@ Qian

U must copy the attrs.xml or its content to your projects attrs.xml. make sure to copy the whole thing like this;

```
 <declare-styleable name="StaggeredGridView">
    <attr name="column_count" format="integer" />
    <attr name="column_count_portrait" format="integer" />
    <attr name="column_count_landscape" format="integer" />
    <attr name="item_margin" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="grid_paddingLeft" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="grid_paddingRight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="grid_paddingTop" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="grid_paddingBottom" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

to your own attires.xml

then in the error file import your own com.example.example in the R.