# How Can I Add A Gradle Library to Android Project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

**Aim & Problem:** *Add Gradle Library to Android Project In Eclipse*

**My Gradle library**

[image]

**When i try to add the gradle library the gradle library isn't on the list**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should configure [multi-module gradle project build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864716/gradle-build-for-set-of-android-projects-including-libraries)

That is you should solve the problem using gradle, not with Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd better do learn how to Importing gradle project to eclipse.
[Importing gradle project to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse)
Then gradle library will exists on your list.