# How to import RippleEffect Library into Eclipe?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use Material Designs Ripple Effect into my project which is lower level of Lollipop. I have Downloaded RippleEffect library from `github.com`. How can I import this library into Eclipse and how to add these third party libraies into my project?

Comment: Try searching google for answers before posting to SO. We will help you after seeing your efforts.
One more thing, check the below links for similar posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168467/how-can-i-add-a-gradle-library-to-android-project-in-eclipse

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can import library by creating POM if eclipse has `maven-android-plugin`. Or do it with `aar` file if eclipse has `gradle-eclipse-aar-plugin`.