# How to Use Android PagerSlidingTabStrip library or any other gradle built library in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I have a problem importing the **PagerSlidingTabStrip** [library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) into Eclipse, I get multiple errors and I know this happens because the library was built using **gradle**.

I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse) but I can't find **use as source folder** in the **build path** menu.

I've never used gradle previously and don't know how to go about this in Eclipse. Please guys, help most of us who have this problem out of our dilemma. Would be very grateful.

Comment: Do you have any error log to show us? How are you importing the library? Please provide us with more info. Thanks!

Comment: I created a new android project from existing code as i would do other libraries, but i get the little red error icon on the project. When i navigate to the lines which are marked most of them are the **cannot be resolved to a type** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay in the end this was what i did:

- I checked the **build.gradle** file of the library for **target and min sdks**. I then put what i found in the **android manifest.xml** which I know **Eclipse** uses.
- I deleted the **build.gradle** and **gradle.properties** files.
- Made sure the project was marked as a library. And it works!

I think the most crucial step was to check the **build.gradle** for the **sdks** and whatever else the project requires and replicating that the way it should be in the **manifest** file.

Comment: You could have left `build.gradle` as secondary build

Comment: Ohh, its working already. whats the takeaway from leaving it?