# Google Play Store Swipeable Tabs

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to implement swipeable tabs like the Google play store. I am developing my android app using eclipse most of the examples I have seen are using android studio and most of the libraries are imported using android studio. Can I please have an example that works or is easy to import in eclipse.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: You should really switch to Android Studio ASAP. Eclipse is no longer Google's recommended IDE. As time goes on, things will get harder and harder to do using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for this. Using SDK Manager download latest Samples for SDK.

In `<android-sdk>\samples\android-21\ui\SlidingTabsBasic\Application\src\main\java\com\example\android\common\view` shamelessly lift `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java`. Modify it slightly to your needs. (I made the bottom line thinner and got rid of dividers - all according to material design specs. It's also a good exercise for understanding how it works.)

You can install the example's app to your phone (or emulator) by running `gradlew installDebug` from command line in `<adnroid-sdk>\samples\android-21\ui\SlidingTabsBasic`.

Comment: Kul thanks, that's a lot of detail. Do you have an example I can follow. for instance how would I do this using this example: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: 1) If you need an example, the whole thing is an example. Explore the whole  `SlidingTabsBasic` folder.  2) If you want to use the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` library, you're going to have to download it, convert it to eclipse and open itas one of your projects [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805715/importing-gradle-project-to-eclipse) might help you.